# Codeigniter - Update DB on each page visit

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm doing my site in Codeigniter, where i need to update the `timestamp` on my table field for each page visit. Since i'm not familiar with the control flow in Codeigniter, i'm confused with where to write the code for this? It should be common to all the pages around the site.

Comment: so put it in common header file

Comment: @dianuj Which is the common file with the db access in codeigniter?

Comment: have you already loaded database library in your controller ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use hooks in application/config/hooks.php

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user_guide/general/hooks.html

```
$hook['pre_controller'] = array(
                            'class'    => 'MyClass',
                            'function' => 'Myfunction',
                            'filename' => 'Myclass.php',
                            'filepath' => 'hooks',
                            'params'   => array('beer', 'wine', 'snacks')
                            );
```

Comment: Is it possible to access db and session from Hook?

Comment: use a post_controller_constructor hook instead. It is called after the controller constructor and before the controller method. It should do the trick for you

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way is probably to put this in your controllers' constructor since that is called on every page load.

Comment: So, do i need to put this in the constructor of every controller?

Comment: Yes. If you abstract it into a model you can get it down to just a couple of lines of code in each contructor.

Comment: You can create a MY_Controller, and put the code in its constructor.

Answer (score 0):

make an model and add model name to config/autoload.php search for line:

> $autoload['model'] = array();

then (after your model is made) all you need to do is request update_entry() function on every contoller;

> $this->update->update_entry();

model example:

> class Update extends CI_Model {
>
> ```
> function update_entry()
> {
>     $timestamp    = time();
>
>     $this->db->where('id',1)->update('entries', array('timestamp' => $timestamp));
> }
> ```
>
> }

Comment: mix this solution with pre_controller hook and you will have what You wanted

Answer (score 0):

OR simple put it in the __Construct